# word文書をHTML化したい。

Tags: html, ms-word

大量のword文書をHTML化しwebページに載せる形にしたいのですが、
wordをHTMLに変換するうまい方法がわからず困って居ます。
word文書を見た目はそのままでHTML化するサービスなどは見つかったのですが、
やりたいことはword文書の見た目をそのままHTML化ではなく、
掲載する予定のwebページに沿った形でHTML化したいため、word文書の見出しや色の指定など基本的な部分はそのまま保ちつつも、idやclassの指定をしてある程度の骨組みをいじりつつ変換したいのです。
言語は問わないので、どういった方法を用いれば達成できるか教えてください。

Comment: 内部情報が全く別物なので恐らく簡単に変換する方法はないと思います…。まずWordを見た目そのままHTML化してそのHTMLをRubyなどで解析してHTMLを生成するか、テキストエディタの複数ファイル一括置換などの機能で行うのが一番マシな方法ではないでしょうか。

Comment: >ironsandさん　さらっとできる簡単な方法はないのですね・・・まず見た目をそのままHTML化して解析してみる方法で検討してみようと思います。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 面倒な方法なので、変換プログラムの開発にどれくらいの工数をかけられるかにもよるかと思うのですが、Word文書がもしdocxであれば、中身はxmlですので直接抜き出すパーサ（スクレイパー？）を書くというのも選択肢としてはあるかもしれません。また、PythonやRuby,PHP,JavaScriptでもdocxのデータにアクセスするためのライブラリなどがあるため、そういったものを利用することも考えられます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/products/words/net)という製品は、docxからhtmlへの変換機能を持っています。有償ですが、試されてはどうでしょうか。

Wordを扱うツールはいろいろありますが、[東アジア言語の書式](https://support.office.com/ja-jp/article/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B8%E5%BC%8F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A-fe29a121-f1b5-4626-bf24-60cc8ab137a9)に対応しているものは少ない印象です。その点でAspose.Wordsはうまく機能しています。（あくまで個人的な実績です。1行の文字数設定の認識、文字間隔の調整など）